# Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem throw error "Account name is invalid. Specify the full account including the domain name."

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am using the latest azurerm 6.13.0.  I am sure I passed in correct data lake store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out a known bug, see here for detail: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7962